# Updating numbers based on hidden cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 18 categories, each category is numbered. 
The spreadsheet changes based on various selections. 
There's a macro, which hides irrelevant rows based on a selection.

Some of the categories are part of the irrelevant rows. 
When they are hidden, the numbers of the categories don't change. 
As a result, the categories can jump from 2. to 5.

Any suggestions on automating the numbers so they update based on hidden rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understodd your question right you could just re-number all the columns every time your code runs and hides things.

```
For i = 0 to num_rows -1 //do whatever steps you need in here
    If cell(i,1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        cell(i,1) = count
        count = count+1 
    End If
Next
```

Something like that should work.
If i got it completely wrong we might need some more info to work with

Comment: Thank you for your help! It didn't seem to work, mostly because it's hard to tell what the category number will be when the rows are hidden.